# Number Line Question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am stomped on the following question

> Which is greater judging from the number line if $\rm JL = KM.$
>
> a) $\rm JK$
>
> b) $\rm LM$
>
> (Answer : Both are the same)

[image]

I would like to know how they concluded both are same ?

Comment: $L-J=M-K\Rightarrow L-M=-K+J\Rightarrow M-L=K-J$.

Comment: @DavidMitra . That makes sense. So on a number line $JL$ can be written as L-J right ?

Comment: Yes, $5-3 = 2$ as in: $-\stackrel{3}{|}-\stackrel{4}{|}-\stackrel{5}{|}-.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

We have $\rm JL = JK + KL$ and $\rm KM = KL + LM.$ (Exercise: why does these equalities hold?). Equate, simplify, and conclude.

Comment: Similar method: JM=JL+LM and also JM=JK+KM, therefore JL+LM=JK+KM (1). JL=KM, so replace JL on LHS of (1) with KM and simplify.